# EF 7 is not releasing the SQLite DB file after migrate

Tags: entity-framework

We recently migrated our EF from 2.0 to 7.0.1. After EF migration, we are facing a challange that sqlite db file not released after calling the DatabaseFacade.Migrate method (we are using the code first apporach). File is open at the EF side due to that unable to access like copy/delete the sqlite db file. Could someone help us on this issue ?

SQlite db has to be release after calling DatabaseFacade.Migrate

Answer (score 0):

The SQLite provider pools connections, improving connection speed significantly but keeping connections open. You can disable pooling by adding Pooling=false to the connection string or calling SqliteConnection.ClearAllPools() at the point where you want them to be closed.

Comment: Thanks ErikEJ, yesterday I got same information in MSDN, like you mentioned Pooling=false resolved. Thank you much for your response